# c++ sample test for Train Composition

Tags: c++11

I've modified the code as below for a sample test as given in 
https://www.testdome.com/for-developers/solve-question/9930

"A TrainComposition is built by attaching and detaching wagons from the left and the right sides.
For example, if we start by attaching wagon 7 from the left followed by attaching wagon 13, again from the left, we get a composition of two wagons (13 and 7 from left to right). Now the first wagon that can be detached from the right is 7 and the first that can be detached from the left is 13.
Implement a TrainComposition that models this problem."

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TrainComposition
{
    //std::vector<int> wagons;

    public:

    std::vector<int> wagons;

    void attachWagonFromLeft(int wagonId)
    {
        wagons.insert(wagons.begin(), wagonId);
    }

    void attachWagonFromRight(int wagonId)
    {
        wagons.push_back(wagonId);
    }

    int detachWagonFromLeft()
    {
        int ret = wagons[0];
        wagons.erase(wagons.begin());
        return ret;
    }

    int detachWagonFromRight()
    {
        int ret = wagons[(int)(wagons.size()) - 1];
        wagons.pop_back();
        return ret;
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    TrainComposition tree;
    tree.attachWagonFromLeft(7);
    tree.attachWagonFromLeft(13);
    std::cout << tree.detachWagonFromRight() << "\n"; // 7 
    std::cout << tree.detachWagonFromLeft() << "\n";; // 13
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

The test result has one fail as 
Performance test with a large number of wagons: Time limit exceeded

Please help to fix this fail...

Comment: You are looking for [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

Comment: Since there is no iteration over the "wagons" a std::list might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample code to solve this problem:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

class TrainComposition
{
public:
    std::deque<int> my_train;

    void showdq() 
    { 
        std::deque <int> :: iterator it; 
        for (it = my_train.begin(); it != my_train.end(); ++it) 
        std::cout << '\t' << *it; 
        std::cout << '\n'; 
    } 

    void attachWagonFromLeft(int wagonId)
    {
        //std::cout << "Attaching Wagon " << wagonId << " from left!"<< std::endl;
        my_train.push_front(wagonId);
    }

    void attachWagonFromRight(int wagonId)
    {
        //std::cout << "Attaching Wagon " << wagonId << " from right!"<< std::endl;
        my_train.push_back(wagonId);
    }

    int detachWagonFromLeft()
    {
        int detachedWagon = my_train.front();
        my_train.pop_front();
        return detachedWagon;
    }

    int detachWagonFromRight()
    {
        int detachedWagon = my_train.back();
        my_train.pop_back();
        return detachedWagon;
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    TrainComposition tree;
    //tree.attachWagonFromLeft(1);
    //tree.attachWagonFromLeft(2);
    tree.attachWagonFromLeft(7);
    tree.attachWagonFromLeft(13);

    //std::cout << "Train's Wagon: ";
    //tree.showdq();

    std::cout << "Detaching " << tree.detachWagonFromRight() << " from right\n"; // 7 
    std::cout << "Detaching "<< tree.detachWagonFromLeft() << " frim left\n"; // 13

    //std::cout << "Train's Wagon After: ";
    //tree.showdq();

}
#endif
```

This is the result I get:

```
Compilation OK

Detaching 7 from right
Detaching 13 frim left 

Your score is 100%, perfect!
```

Please note printing with `std::cout` (uncomment above) can cause the following result:

```
Performance test with a large number of wagons: Time limit exceeded
Your score is 67%, nice!
```